# Custom 503 error page in SharePoint

Tags: iis, sharepoint

Can someone let me know how to set up custom 503 error page when the solution is deployed ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753103(v=ws.10).aspx

*You cannot customize the following HTTP errors: 400, 403.9, 411, 414, 500, 500.11, 500.14, 500.15, 501, 503, and 505.*